# java.sql.SQLException: Error reading from InputStream com.sun.mail.util.DecodingException

Tags: java, email, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am creating a mail client with JavaMail. 
I have successfully received emails and they are being entered into the database for the most part. The content-disposition is not being entered into the database properly. 
I am having trouble with importing inline objects into the database.

The following is the code that I have written and am implementing in my mail client:
**

```
String filename = part.getFileName();
File f = new File(filename);
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(part.getInputStream());
psINLINE.setBinaryStream(1, in);
```

The following error code is received:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Error reading from InputStream com.sun.mail.util.DecodingException
Caused by: com.sun.mail.util.DecodingException: BASE64Decoder: Error in encoded stream: needed at least 2 valid base64 characters, but only got 1 before padding character (=), the 10 most recent characters were: "%\164L\128\192<\160<\163="
```

This only occurs on incoming gmails. All other incoming mail works fine. 
Can you help me out with this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What version of JavaMail are you using?

What does the [protocol trace](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?

This usually only happens when the message is incorrectly formatted or encoded.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I`m using JavaMail 1.5.
I checked the log and it shows there is no problem, but if when the following code is reached a error arises : `psINLINE.executeUpdate();`
I`m not too certain about what you mean by the protocol trace. I assumed it was the log.
Could you tell me how to fix this error. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you follow my link above?

Comment: Thank you for the link. After arriving at the conditional statement System.setProperty("mail.mime.base64.ignoreerrors", "true"), there was no error for the com.sun.mail.util.DecodingException. However, when I check the protocol trace, the base64 for the encoded image is corrupted/garbled. I would like to return the corrupted text back to ASCII-TEXT. This occurs only with gmails that use the "Google Photo" feature. Other mail clients work fine. I was able to successfully retrieve images before google updated this feature.

Comment: Well, maybe you should be talking to Google?  if you need help figuring out what's going on, post the protocol trace here, perhaps with a copy of a sample message that demonstrates the problem.  Or, send those details to me at javamail_ww@oracle.com.